# Handle keyboard interrupts by polling interrupt request register (for x86)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, interrupt-handling, interrupt

I need to develop program for x86 that will handle keyboard interrupts by polling IRR. Program should work in real-mode under ms-dos. My main issue is that it don't work as I think it should work: appropriate IRR bit has non zero value even if no keys were pressed and value that was read from the port 0x60 is always 0x1c.
Can someone explain me what I did wrong?
Here is my polling loop:

```
        in al,21h       ; read old IMR value
        or al,02h       ; disable handling of interrupts from IRQ1
        out 21h,al      ; update IMR value
READ_LOOP:
        mov al,0ah
        out 20h,al
        in al,20h       ; read IRR value
        and al, 02h     ; check request from IRQ1
        jz READ_LOOP
        in al,60h       ; read data from keyboard buffer
        mov dl,al
        and dl,7fh      ; ignore most significant bit value
        mov ah,2h       ; print char
        int 21h
        jmp READ_LOOP
```

Thanx!

**Update**
I missed the fact that keyboard buffer contains scan codes, so 0x1c seems to be scan code of return key. =)

Comment: You cannot mess with the PIC while leaving other IRQs enabled.  You'll have to disable *all* of them so their respective interrupt handlers don't address the PIC anymore at the same time your loop is running.  It makes completely no sense to do this.

Comment: @HansPassant, The only one reason why I implementing interrupt handling this way is to know how to work with IMR and IRR. So I should disable all interrupts and provide appropriate actions for all of them in my loop? Solution when some interrupts will be handled by their handlers (as it is in my code) is not correct at all?